# In which format should I send the date data?

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart

So I have a **Django** **Flutter** setup where I run an app that gets data from the a rest api server on my pc.

I created a serilizer for creating users in **Django**, here is the code:

```py
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'email', 'password', 'gender', 'date_of_contamination', 'cluster_id_id']
```

And knowing that this is my user model:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cronic_disease_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    cronic_disease_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    cronic_disease_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    cronic_disease_4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    cronic_disease_5 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    cluster_id = models.ForeignKey('Cluster', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    if_transmit = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    date_of_contamination = models.DateField(null=True)
    recommandation = models.FloatField(null=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(date_of_birth__lte=datetime.date.today()), name='no_future_date_of_birth')
        ]
```

After creating a post request api url that works (tested it with **Postman**) I tried to create a post request to send data from **Flutter**, here is my post request method:

```dart
static Future<bool> postRegisterUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required DateTime dateOfBirth,
    required Gender gender,
    DateTime? dateOfContamination,
  }) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'first_name': firstName,
      'last_name': lastName,
      'date_of_birth': dateOfBirth,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'gender': gender.toStringValue().capitalize,
      'date_of_contamination': dateOfContamination,
      'cluster_id': 0,
    };

    final response = await Dio().post(postCreateUserUrl, data: data);
    return response.statusCode == 200 ? true : false;
  }
```

Now when I try to send a post query I'm getting errors like this one:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.

And this one:

> E/flutter (18370): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [unknown]: null
> E/flutter (18370): Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'

Knowing that for a test a printed the `data` variable before sending it, and here is it:

```py
{first_name: fkqsjmdfk, last_name: qfjsmkdfjm, date_of_birth: 2002-09-14, email: fqsfjkkmqsj, password: dskjfqmskj, gender: Homme, date_of_contamination: 2023-05-18, cluster_id: 0}
```

And for more clarity here is the datatype of each field contained inside the `data` varible before sending it:

```dart
email: fqsfjkkmqsj String
password: dskjfqmskj String
first name: fkqsjmdfk String
last name: qfjsmkdfjm String
date of birth: 2002-09-14 00:00:00.000 DateTime
gender: Homme String
date of contamination: 2023-05-18 22:59:35.456108 DateTime
```

Comment: You can either use an ISO 8601 string, or milliseconds since epoch integer.  You just have to be sure both ends of the wire agree.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally fixed the problem. The problem was first I was sending a `DateTime` **Dart** datatype which was not supported by the **Django** server, it was expecting a **String**, and because I wasn't encoding the data to the proper **JSon** format and I didn't add the proper header data.

Here is the correct way of sending a post request:

```dart
static Future<bool> postRegisterUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required DateTime dateOfBirth,
    required Gender gender,
    DateTime? dateOfContamination,
  }) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        'first_name': firstName,
        'last_name': lastName,
        'date_of_birth': dateOfBirth.toString().split(' ')[0], // converting to the proper datatype
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'gender': gender.toStringValue().capitalize,
        'date_of_contamination': dateOfContamination.toString().split(' ')[0], // converting to the proper datatype
        'cluster_id': 0,
      };

      var encodedData = json.encode(data); // encoding the datatype to the json format

      final url = Uri.parse(postCreateUserUrl);
// Here I'm using the http package instead of dio package, I think it's better when it comes to displaying what the error is
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: encodedData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, // adding the propert heading to tell the Django server that it's a json file
      );
      return response.statusCode == 200 ? true : false;
    } on DjangoException catch (failure) {
      throw DjangoFailure(failure.message);
    }
  }
```